# PostgreSQL - Reference a variable value in select statement interval

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm trying to calculate a value in a variable then use that value to drive a interval statement further on.

Running on PG 9.6.
We can get to PG 13 if there is something added since then we can use.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.demofunc(
    int,
    int,
    date)
    returns date
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
    DECLARE 
       diffvalue text;
       returndate date;    
    BEGIN
    diffvalue:= ($2 - $1);
    returndate := (SELECT $3 - INTERVAL 'diffvalue days');

    return returndate;
    END$$;
```

This is a simplified version of what I want to achieve, the interval of the numbers of days to remove is based on a calculation that's done in the function. So its not a simple A - B but the end result is

I can't seem to get the function to resolve the "diffvalue" before running the select statement. I've tried using int and text and varchar and concat the string for anything.

Sorry for anything obvious i might be missing, only started this today.

Comment: You can't assign the result of a numeric operation (`-`)  to a `text` value. `diffvalue` should be declared as `int` as well. There is also no need to use "anonymous" parameters. If you give your function parameters names, the whole thing is way easier to read.

Comment: Since 9.6 has reached EOL and is no longer supported, you should upgrade. But why just 13, when current release is 14.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `diffvalue` is in reality an `integer`, you can use the `make_interval` function to create an interval based on that number:

```
returndate := $3 + make_interval(days => diffvalue);
```

If diffvalue is a decimal that can represent fractional days, `make_interval` can't be used.

In that case you can multiply an interval of 1 day with that value:

```
returndate := $3 + interval '1 day' * diffvalue;
```